# Draw a circle with different stroke color using Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw a circle with one color (for example, blue) and with stroke with another color (for example, white). I figured out how to draw stroke, but now my circle doesn't have own color. Hot to add different color to stroke and circle itself?

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);

    paint.setColor(getColor(R.color.lineColor));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 20, paint);
```

Comment: You can draw two circles with two paint objects, right?

Comment: @RameesThattarath sure, but It will cause on performance, right? The problem is that I will have a lot of rerender in my app